# Getting a wrong Error response in catch block when using along with async await

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, async-await, try-catch

```
async function run() {
        try {
          const data = await VarifyPanDetails(
            leadData.leadId,
            leadData.leadApplicantId,
            doc_id,
            {
              name: sectionValues.panDetails.fullName,
              panNumber: sectionValues.panDetails.panNumber,
              dob:
                sectionValues.panDetails.year.value +
                '-' +
                sectionValues.panDetails.month.value +
                '-' +
                sectionValues.panDetails.date.value,
              fatherName: sectionValues.panDetails.fatherName
            }
          );
          const { verified, message } = data;
          if (verified === false) throw new Error('VARIFICATION_FAILED');
          else throw new Error('VARIFICATION_SUCCESS');
        } catch (err) {
          if (err.message === 'VARIFICATION_FAILED')
            throw new Error('VARIFICATION_FAILED');
          else if (err.message === 'VARIFICATION_SUCCESS')
            throw new Error('VARIFICATION_SUCCESS');
          else throw new Error(err);
        }
      }
      await run();
```

hi i was trying to get the `error` in `catch(err)` block if in case the `VarifyPanDetails` api above fails , but when it does it giving [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4KRY.png) if u console it, but network tap its showing [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvHvd.png) ,
how its not showing the throwing the same `error` as network tab i.e `err` in the console should have `err.status===400` and `err.message==="Invalid PAN Number"` but instead of that its showing `err.message:Error.false`

Comment: Just try to `console.log(err)` and see what you're getting